# How to find list of all Hive tables in a database that are missing compute stats?

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala, hadoop-partitioning

As part of my current project, we deployed 100+ hive tables. I am trying to find list of all hive tables in a particular database that are missing compute stats. For an individual table, I used *SHOW PARTITIONS table_name*. Is there anyway I can find for all hive tables that are missing stats?

Comment: I checked that question before posting my query. Not the one I am looking for. I am trying to find list of tables where #Rows = -1

Comment: do you have access to hive metastore in order to take the information from there?

Comment: No, only admins have access to hive metastore